# SpringBoot MySQL - Could not connect to database from log4j: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, database, docker, server

I am using Docker to docker-compose a NodeJS webapp, server-side SpringBoot and MySQL database.

When I am trying to add a participant to the database from my webapp I get this error on my Chrome/Safari console:
[Image of Safari Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYt68.png)

And I have this output on my docker terminal:
[Image of Docker Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBLK7.jpg)

I have tried to add .allowHeaders to my Server-side Application.java code, but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
I simply changed my CorsFilter, from:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

to:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```